# PayPal API, account verification

Tags: asp.net, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments

**Use-case**

1. I am implementing a trading application
2. I am using PayPal API for express checkout
3. Subscribers should be able to sell & buy using PayPal account
4. Subscriber should associate his Trading application account with his PayPal account using the e-mail address registered with PayPal

**Problem**
Using PayPal API, Is it possible to verify that the PayPal account e-mail address provided is registered with PayPal? ( sending an e-mail activation link will not help here )

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Try using the Paypal AddressVerify API: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/AddressVerify_API_Operation_NVP/

AddressVerify can also check that your user's address and ZIP/postal code are correct.

AddressVerify API isn't provided by Paypal on default. I think you have to talk to customer support to give you access to it, and then contact them again for approval to have it on your site.

Comment: This will verify the Address & ZipCode, not the e-mail address, is there any way to verify the PayPal e-mail address ?

Comment: It validates the email too. "(Required) Email address of a PayPal member to verify."